# Selenium Java: How to read data from Excel with annotations

Tags: java, excel, selenium

Using DataProvider annotation & gradle as Dependency Manager.

Have questions:

1. To read data from excel file, do jxl needs to be downloaded ?
2. If I try to read the url (which is in some cell) from excel file, will the url be opened using driver.get method?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the apache poi library to read the xls  file.. maven dependency and jar file is here..

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml/3.9

Sample Code:

Assumption is you have dropped the xls on the project folder.. if not give the full path of the xlsx.

You can pass the sheetName and which Row you wanted to read you can pass to this method.. or you can create your own method by referring this.

```
public static HashMap<String, String> ReadExcel(String SheetName, int Rownumber) throws IOException {
        // Define the File Folder
        XSSFWorkbook sourceBook = new XSSFWorkbook("./MasterSheet.xlsx");
        //Which sheet you want to read (Sheet Name)
        XSSFSheet sourceSheet = sourceBook.getSheet(SheetName);
        //int lastRowNumber = sourceSheet.getLastRowNum();
        int lastColumnNumber = sourceSheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum() - 1;
        //Read the headerRow
        XSSFRow headerRow = sourceSheet.getRow(0);
        HashMap<String, String> ValuesMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for (int i = 0; i <= lastColumnNumber; i++) {
            ValuesMap.put(headerRow.getCell(i).toString(), sourceSheet.getRow(Rownumber).getCell(i).toString());
            //System.out.println(sourceSheet.getRow(Rownumber).getCell(i).toString());
        }
        //Close the workbook 
        sourceBook.close();
        return ValuesMap;
    }
```

You can use the returned value by K,V pair and reading like..

```
HashMap<String, String> queryset = utilities.ReadExcel("CardDetails", 1);
String urlvalue = queryset.get(url).toString();
driver.get(urlvalue)
```

Comment: Hi since I am using Gradle would Apache poi library work?

Comment: since I am using Gradle would Apache poi library work?

Comment: Yes. It will work..if u open the given link, you can get the gradle as of the tab option..